# Python beatuifulsoup: extract value from div class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to build a program that automatically gets the live price of the german index (DAX). Therefore i use a [website](https://news.guidants.com/#Ticker/Profil/?i=133962&e=74) with the price provider FXCM.

In my code i use beautifulsoup and requests as packages. The div Box where the current value is stored looks like this :

```html
<div class="left" data-item="quoteContainer" data-bg_quotepush="133962:74:bid">
      <div class="wrapper cf">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="quote quote_standard" data-bg_quotepush="quote" data-bg_quotepush_i="133962:74:bid" data-bg_quotepush_f="quote" data-bg_quotepush_c="40">13.599,24</span>
          <span class="label" data-bg_quotepush="time" data-bg_quotepush_i="133962:74:bid" data-bg_quotepush_f="time" data-bg_quotepush_c="41">25.12.2020</span>
          <span class="label"> • </span>
          <span class="label" data-item="currency"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <span class="percent up" data-bg_quotepush="percent" data-bg_quotepush_i="133962:74:bid" data-bg_quotepush_f="percent" data-bg_quotepush_c="42">+0,00<span>%</span></span>
          <span class="label up" data-bg_quotepush="change" data-bg_quotepush_i="133962:74:bid" data-bg_quotepush_f="change" data-bg_quotepush_c="43">0,00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The value i want to have is the one after `data-bg_quotepush_c="40"` and has a vaulue of `13.599,24`.

My Python code looks like this:

```py
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
url = "https://news.guidants.com/#Ticker/Profil/?i=133962&e=74"
    
response = rq.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text, "lxml")

price = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"left"})[0].find("span")

print(price["data-bg_quotepush_c"])
```

It returns the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Felix\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__ 
return self.attrs[key]

KeyError: 'data-bg_quotepush_c'
```

Comment: You're searching for a `div` element but the data you want is in a `span` element within that `div`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel: in bs4 it is done the right way, but i agree, it could be improved e.g. like this: `soup.find("span", {"class":"quote quote_standard"}).text`

Answer (score 0):

Use Selenium instead of requests if working with dynamically generated content

**What is going on?**

Requesting the website with `requests` just provide the initial content, that not contains all the dynamically generatet information, so you can not find what your looking for.

To wait until website loaded completely use `Selenium` and `sleep()` as simple method or [selenium waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in advanced.

**Avoiding the error**

Use `price.text` to get the text of the element that looks like this:

`<span class="quote quote_standard" data-bg_quotepush="quote" data-bg_quotepush_c="40" data-bg_quotepush_f="quote" data-bg_quotepush_i="133962:74:bid">13.599,24</span>`

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://news.guidants.com/#Ticker/Profil/?i=133962&e=74"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib")
price = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"left"})[0].find("span")
print(price.text)
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
13.599,24
```

Answer (score -1):

if you scraping the value of div class try this, example

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(YourPATH to driver)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# create variable to store a url strings
url = 'https://news.guidants.com/#Ticker/Profil/?i=133962&e=74'

driver.get(url)

# scraping proccess

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib")

# parse
prices = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"left"})

for price in prices:
    total_price = price.find('span')

# close the driver
driver.close()
```

if you using requests module try use different parser
you can install with pip example `html5lib`

`pip install html5lib`

thanks